Retrieve xcom return value from SQSSensor returns None
I have an SQSSensor DAG that returns the value as XCom push the values, see here:

But, when I try to receive it and print the value, the PythonOperator returns None. This is the code:
# DAG Config
CALENDAR = "*/5 * * * *"

default_args = {
    "owner": "myname",
    "email": ["my@gmail.com"],
    "start_date": datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 23),
    "catchup": False,
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "retries": 4,
    "retry_delay": datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
}

with DAG(
    "my_dag",
    default_args=default_args,
    description="My DAG",
    schedule=CALENDAR,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    start = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")
    end = EmptyOperator(task_id="end")

    # Define the SqsSensor
    read_from_queue = SqsSensor(
        task_id="read_from_queue",
        sqs_queue=Variable.get("SQS_URL"),
        max_messages=10,  # The max number of messages you want to process at a time
        wait_time_seconds=20,
        visibility_timeout=30,
        # delete_message_on_reception=True,
        # mode="reschedule",  # Use reschedule mode to free the worker slot between pokes
        poke_interval=60,  # Custom poke interval in seconds
        soft_fail=True,  # Soft fail if no messages are received
    )

    def process_and_display_messages(sqs_messages):
        if not sqs_messages:
            raise ValueError("No messages received from SQS queue.")
        
        print(sqs_messages)

    display_messages = PythonOperator(
        task_id='display_messages',
        python_callable=process_and_display_messages,
        op_kwargs={"sqs_messages": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='read_from_queue', key='return_value') }}"},
    )

    # Set the task dependencies
    start >> read_from_queue >> display_messages >> end

What did I do wrong? The return value is a list of dictionaries.
